# How to print out HashMap value? Output like xxx@da52a1

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 2 classes.

Main.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    Map<Integer, Row> rows = new HashMap<Integer, Row>();
    private Row col;

    public Main() {
        col = new Row();
        show();
    }

    public void show() {
        // col.setCol("one", "two", "three");
        // System.out.println(col.getCol());

        Row p = new Row("raz", "dwa", "trzy");
        Row pos = rows.put(1, p);
        System.out.println(rows.get(1));

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "AA: " + rows;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

and Row.java

```
public class Row {

    private String col1;
    private String col2;
    private String col3;

    public Row() {
        col1 = "";
        col2 = "";
        col3 = "";
    }

    public Row(String col1, String col2, String col3) {
        this.col1 = col1;
        this.col2 = col2;
        this.col3 = col3;
    }

    public void setCol(String col1, String col2, String col3) {
        this.col1 = col1;
        this.col2 = col2;
        this.col3 = col3;
    }

    public String getCol() {
        return col1 + " " + col2 + " " + col3;
    }
}
```

Output always looks like "Row@da52a1" or similar. How to fix that? I want to be able to do something like this with easy access to each of strings:

```
str="string1","string2","string3"; // it's kind of pseudocode ;)
rows.put(1,str);
rows.get(1);
```

As you can see, I've created class Row to use its as object of Map, but I have no idea what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `toString` method to your `Row` class like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return col1 + " " + col2 + " " + col3;
}
```

Comment: @Baadshah I've got this values so I think it is working well. Thanks durron597 :)

Comment: @tmq No problem, don't forget to click the green checkmark :)

Comment: @tmq thats the reason i gave +1 for durron  :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom `toString` method to the `Row` class.  `toString` is  a method that every Java object has.  It exists for situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

Override toString method in your Row class, and print values you want to print

in your case this method should be as follows,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return col1 + " " + col2 + " " + col3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> System.out.println(rows.get(1));

`rows.get(1)` will return Object of type `Row`. Therefore, when you print it to console, it will print the object.

To fix the issue, you can implement and override `toString()` function in the Row class that returns String.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting **Row@da52a1**, because you end up calling **String's default `toString` method**, which combines the class name with hash code of the object in hex notation.

By creating your own `toString` method, you can tell the compiler what values to display whenever you call `toString` on your object.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.col1 + " " + this.col2 + " " + this.col3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return "AA: " + rows;   its calling toString method on Row object
```

actually you have to append the  each column val

try

```
return "AA: " +col1 + " " + col2 + " " + col3;  //typo edited
```